# nVidia prime: external monitor only recognizes 4:3 aspect ratios

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, external-monitor, nvidia-prime

I'm running 14.04 on my laptop with dual graphic cards. (Geforce 610m + integrated Intel) Previously everything worked fine, but the other day I unplugged the external monitor and since I plugged it in the resolution has been stuck at 4:3 ratio and the monitor is listed as "not recognized". I hadn't done any updates, just disconnect / connect the monitor.

I use nvidia-prime and the nvidia-352.63 drivers from the official respository. I tried the newest versions from the graphics-update ppa and that didn't work either.

Any help is greatly appreciated! (And happy Easter, everyone!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I connected the monitor via HDMI instead of my good old VGA cable. Everything works now. No idea how this happened, but a good workaround.